# No Steam Powered Icon

Tags: wine, steam, winetricks

I installed steam using wine recently because of some steam games not working. When I installed it using SteamInstall.msi with winetricks and wine it did give me an icon but it says this 
Details: Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/steam" (No such file or directory).
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be suffering from a bit of Confusion. So you had steam (Linux version) installed. Then went and installed the windows version using wine. It looks like you then removed the Linux version. So now when you try to launch steam via icon, your actually trying to run the Linux version which is not installed anymore.

So here is my recommendation.

1. Install the Linux version again, and use it where you can.
2. Remove wine
3. Install [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/) it's the same as wine (even made the same people it's just their supported version).
4. Install steam via a [CrossTie](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=206)
5. This will give you a Linux version of steam along side a windows version. You can (and should) use the Linux version for games that support it, like HL2, and use the windows version for games that do not have Linux versions like CIM2.

Now as a fair note, I think crossover's support is worth it, but you can do it with wine, or Play on Linux, but there often more configuring an it's not as smooth (not to mention the lack of real support).